# Outlook 2016 Web Addin Showing in wrong plce

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I recent create a Outlook Web Addin and works great in Outlook 16 (Office 365 subscrition).
The problem is: some users have Outlook 2016 and the web addin don´t show as task panel. Show above attachment area, the addin name is INTERx..

[image]

any one know how to show as a task panel?

Comment: How does your manifest look like?

Comment: In manifest i have: <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>

Comment: And    <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>

Comment: Because i have a SupportsPinning

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue with a newly created sample add-in?

Comment: i have this AddIn (same  manifest) in 2 diferent Outlooks. Outlook 2016 no have taskpanel, Outlook office 365 its fine.

Comment: Did you try a newly created empty add-in? Does it give the same results?

Comment: yes, it is the same.

Comment: Can you share the manifest file of the sample add-in you tried?

Comment: What are the build and version of Outlook and Windows where the add-in does not show up? Please note that pinning is only supported starting with requirement set 1.5 and using Microsoft 365. Outlook 2016 only supports up to requirement set 1.4. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/pinnable-taskpane

Comment: In addition, for your add-in to show up on the ribbon, you should try to add the add-in icon to VersionOverrides1.0 in the manifest as a fall back since Outlook 2016 cannot process VersionOverrides1.1.